# automatically logging flask's messages to a logger

Tags: python, logging, flask

I was following [Flask's documentation on how to configure logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file). However, it seems that it does not write to the logger unless I explicitly tell it to (and the documentation seems to agree.)

Here is how I configured my logger, within `create_app()`

```
def create_app(environment):
  """ creates the flask application. Uses a parameter to choose which config to use """
  app = Flask(__name__)
  # ...

  error_handler = RotatingFileHandler(
    os.path.join(app.config['LOG_FOLDER'], 'flask.log'),
    maxBytes=100000,
    backupCount=1
  )
  error_handler.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
  error_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
  ))
  app.logger.addHandler(error_handler)
```

Now I want it such that, whenever an error occurs like it would in the debugger, to put the traceback in the log. Is this possible while on production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to register an error handler with [`teardown_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request):

```
@app.teardown_request
def log_errors(error):
    if error is None:
        return

    app.logger.error("An error occurred while handling the request", error)
```

Comment: seems like you answer all of my flask questions, but this is an easy and elegant solution, thank you